# How to upgrade angularjs with jquery to angular 9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I have a project in angularjs and I want to upgrade this project to Angular9.

The problem is most of the project uses jQuery features such as query-ui, selectors, change the dom, animations, bootstrap and more.

Say it may only my problem since **I do not want to use jQuery after the upgrade**, just to do stuff in the angular way. so I guess to convert jQuery to angular.

I wonder if there is a way to do that? or I need to go manually and remove the jQuery code to new one?
I know I can import jQuery to my project, but sometimes I use `$('#some').innerHtml('bla')` and this is not what I want to do in my new code.

What are the ideas or approaches should I consider and use?

Comment: Are you wanting the site to look and behave in exactly the same way after the upgrade, or do you also want to take the opportunity to upgrade at least the aesthetics of the site? jQuery UI was great for its time but looks a little dated now.

Comment: I think some minor changing. like the animations will work as before, dropdown and the logic that upgrade the dom.. I know it hard to keep everything works as before. but except some cases I prefer to keep the website flow. so I think if anyone have knowledge to share here.